# RxDart. BehaviorSubject & Distinct

Tags: dart, angular-dart, rxdart

I'm using `BehaviorSubject` and it's emitting back last item on subscription as expected. However, sometimes, data is not changed and and with new `listen` event will be triggered back with last emitted item.

Would be nice to use `distinct` to remove duplicated data. However on new `listen` event stream recreated and doesn't have history. Besides that last item. Any sane solution to handle such situation? To summarize, how we can keep using `BehaviorSubject`, but filter/distinct last item?

Answer (score 1):

```
final _subject = BehaviorSubject<String>();
get Stream<String> distinctSubject => _subject.stream.distinct();
```

and you probably shouldn't do listen() too often either

Answer (score 1):

Create subsclass of BehaviourSubject and override `add` method, so you could store all added items in `set` variable and check for `_set.containts(newItem);`